# Convert a text inside of header to an array of bytes

Tags: c

i am programming an SI4362 using an STM32.  the SI Labs program outputs a header file, and for the sake of ease i would like to simply plug the header into my program however it defines an array of byte like this:

```
#define RF_POWER_UP 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80
```

and i need to convert it to look like this:

```
uint8_t RF_POWER_UP[7] = { 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80 };
```

i could not find anything through the search feature that made this work directly within the C program.

Comment: One question per question, and do not modify an existing question after it has answers, *especially* in a way that invalidates existing answers or renders them incomplete.  If you have another question then ask it **as** another question.  Rolling back...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The macro definition that is already being produced seems designed specifically for purposes similar to yours.  You cannot easily re-use the macro name as your array's name, but you can certainly do this:

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include "the_generated_header.h"

uint8_t rf_power_up[] = { RF_POWER_UP };
```

If you do not specify the array length, as shown, then it will be made exactly long enough to accommodate all the elements of the initializer.  That means you don't need to know in advance how many values will be produced (though there needs to be at least one).

Comment: This works great as the standard definitions wont be changing name but possibly size which gives me a follow up question added to the original

Answer (score 1):

> Convert a text inside of header to an array of bytes

An alternative to using the macro for initialization of a named object is to use it to define an array via a *compound literal*.

Use `(unsigned char[]){RF_POWER_UP}` wherever you need an _array.  This directly meets OP's stated goal.

```
#define RF_POWER_UP 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80

printf("Size %zu\n", sizeof  (unsigned char[]){RF_POWER_UP});  / prints 7.
```

No need for a named object:

```
#define RF_POWER_UP_ARRAY (unsigned char[]){RF_POWER_UP}
fwrite(RF_POWER_UP_ARRAY, sizeof RF_POWER_UP_ARRAY, 1, stream);
```