# Clarification on arrays within define declarations

Tags: c, stm32, stm32cubeide

Working with SI Labs radios, a header file is produced from the provided software in order to initialize the radio. i have been helped tremendously already with the C program here on Stack Overflow and am hopeful this is another simple oversite on my side. in the header file, there are definitions like so:

```
#define RF_POWER_UP 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80
#define RF_GPIO_PIN_CFG 0x13, 0x11, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00
```

which i have placed within arrays for calling within a loop to send over SPI:

```
uint8_t rf_power_up[] = { RF_POWER_UP };
uint8_t rf_gpio_pin_cfg[] = { RF_GPIO_PIN_CFG };
...
   
uint8_t *theProgram[] = { rf_power_up, rf_gpio_pin_cfg, rf_global_xo_tune_1,
...
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, theProgram[i], radio_array[i], 50);
```

this works but if i make changes to the config in the future the header file can completely change.  that makes building manual arrays for the file tedious, however this array below is always included.

```
    #define RADIO_CONFIGURATION_DATA_ARRAY { \
        0x07, RF_POWER_UP, \
        0x08, RF_GPIO_PIN_CFG, \
        ....
```

this declaration has size of each definition followed by the name of the definition previously declared earlier in the header with a final value of 0x00.  i cant seem to figure out how to use this in order to simplify future modifications as to not have to custom rewrite the header file every time i make changed to the prototype.

i was thinking something along the lines of:

```
uint8_t *config_array[] = {RADIO_CONFIGURATION_DATA_ARRAY};
int ix = 0;
while(config_array[ix] != 0x00){
HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, config_array[ix+1], config_array[ix], 50);
ix++;
}
```

any help is much appreciated

Comment: Rather than hard code 7 in `0x07, RF_POWER_UP,`, derive the 7 as [answered before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73888685/2410359).

Comment: You should generally try to minimize manual changes in headers or other code created by some configuration program. That causes work everytime you update something.

Comment: `uint8_t *config_array[]` Why an array of pointers? You just saw in the [other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73896522/defining-array-of-bytes-for-use-to-call-later-in-c-program) how such a blob is stored in an array

Comment: I wonder why that configuration tool only produces the header part. The tools I use (from TI or MicroChip) also produce some C code that uses the definitiones from the headers. Did you disable some options in that tool?

Comment: @Gerhardh i was unsure if the declaration definition would contain the previous defined bytes, although it would define as a macro in the IDE i couldnt find a way to utilize it.  in university i only worked on C++ and java but am working on this prototype for proof of concept before reaching out to a fill time software guy

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that macro contains all commands you are required to send via SPI.

That could be done like this:

```c
uint8_t config_array[] = RADIO_CONFIGURATION_DATA_ARRAY;

size_t pos = 0;
while (pos < sizeof config_array / sizeof *config_array)
{
  uint8 len = config_array[pos];
  HAL_SPI_Transmit(&hspi1, &config_array[pos+1], len, 50);
  pos += len +1;
}
```

The created array will look like this:

```
uint8_t config_array[] = {
 0x07, 0x02, 0x01, 0x01, 0x01, 0xC9, 0xC3, 0x80,
 0x08, 0x13, 0x11, 0x14, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00,
...
};
```

This time we cannot directly address some message based on index because the length varies. Instead we must walk through the array and jump from message to message.
But as we want to send each message, we need to do that anyway.

Comment: You have redundant `{}` in the declaration (there are already brackets in the macro), which will cause at least a warning from the compiler.

Comment: So to understand what we are doing here. we have an array containing the values of RADIO_CONFIGURATION_DATA_ARRAY  then declare an integer for location. loop while pos is less than size of entire array / the location of the array we are pointing to. declare an unsigned int to hold the byte (size) then transmit data at position 2 and length correctly. ................ does this mean that the length of the entire array is actually just every byte in sequence so the definitiouns count as there total bytes not just a single address?

Comment: @ChrisDodd Thanks. That tool seems to be a bit flexible with the format of data it creates.

Comment: @RyanTC that macro only holds an initializer list with lots of numbers that are used to initialize that `uint8_t` array. The size is equal to the number of values in your macro. No addresses are involved except when we index into the array and pick the length and send the content.

Comment: @Gerhardh thank you i am understanding it now. i keep thinking of definitions as a variable but in extremely laymen terms one could say its more of a placeholder therefore calling it to use it is similar to just typing out the values within

Comment: You are mixing things. Strictly speaking, macros are not exactly part of C language but of the C preprocessor. Macro definitions cause text replacement in your code. Wherever you drop them, they are replaced by their content. That is basically plain text replacement. Only after that is done, C compiler is seeing your code. And in C a definition creates a variable or a function.